# T-test with two grouping variables

Tags: r

I would like to conduct t-tests for differences in age between sex (male,female), but with an additional grouping variable grp (a,b). The data is in a data frame (df).

This gets me age by sex for the whole sample:

```
with(df, t.test(age~sex))
```

This gets me age by group for the whole sample:

```
with(df, t.test(age~grp))
```

I would like age by sex and group, i.e. females in a vs females in b, and males in a vs males in b.

Comment: Do an ANOVA followed by a post-hoc test for the pairwise comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With native R:

```
lapply(split(df,df$sex),function(x)with(x, t.test(age~grp)))

$f

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  age by grp
t = 1.3978, df = 42.029, p-value = 0.1695
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -3.241762 17.854665
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
       56.50000        49.19355 


$m

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  age by grp
t = 0.33265, df = 36.741, p-value = 0.7413
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -7.457013 10.385584
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
       54.00000        52.53571
```

Comment: Thank you Robert, the split() function is exactly what was needed. Very helpfu.l

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(
  age = sample(x = 20:80, 100, TRUE),
  sex = sample(c("m", "f"), 100, TRUE),
  grp = sample(1:2, 100, TRUE)
)

library(plyr)

# Split df by "sex" and apply function to each subset of df. Returns a list of the return values.
dlply(.data = df, .variables = "sex", .fun = function(x) {
  with(x, t.test(age~grp))
})
```

Comment: Change `df` to `x` or you end up considering the hole sample: `with(x, t.test(age~grp))`

Comment: Thank you, I edited my answer. Typical copy and paste mistake …